# Could not instantiate implementation: AstyanaxStoreManager

Tags: java, maven, cassandra, titan

I try to access the Titan graph database with Cassandra backend and everything works fine with the following code:

```
    package ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy;

    import ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.ITreeSerializer;
    import ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.TitanSerializer;

    public class ConnectionOkDriver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ITreeSerializer serializer = TitanSerializer.getInstance();
            if (serializer.dbConnected()) {
                System.out.print("connection ok");
            } else {
                System.out.print("connection NOT ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Output (ignore the SLF4J error):

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    connection ok
```

Now if I start the following main method I get a `Could not instantiate implementation` error:

```
    package ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.input;

    import ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.ITreeSerializer;
    import ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.TitanSerializer;

    public class ConnectionFailsDriver {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ITreeSerializer serializer = TitanSerializer.getInstance();
            if (serializer.dbConnected()) {
                System.out.print("connection ok");
            } else {
                System.out.print("connection NOT ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Output (again ignore the SLF4J error):

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at    ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.input.ConnectionFailsDriver.main(ConnectionFailsDriver.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation:    com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:274)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:227)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:97)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:440)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.StandardTitanGraph.<init>(StandardTitanGraph.java:67)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:40)
at ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.TitanSerializer.<init>(TitanSerializer.java:88)
at ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm.twhc.clusterhierarchy.persistence.TitanSerializer.<clinit>(TitanSerializer.java:78)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:263)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.netflix.astyanax.AstyanaxContext.getClient()Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.<init>(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:166)
... 13 more
```

As you can see the classes `ConnectionOkDriver` and `ConnectionFailsDriver` only differ in the package definition. However, the two classes are contained in different maven modules (2whc-clustering-impl depends on 2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl). I would like to post an image of my project structure, but I'm not allowed to do so :(. Here is a link to the image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48169775/project-structure.png

The error occurs in the constructor of my `TitanSerializer` object at `TitanFactory.open(conf)`. This is the code:

```
    private static final String DB_TYPE = "cassandra";
    private static final String DB_IP = "127.0.0.1";
    private TitanSerializer() {
            Configuration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
            conf.setProperty("storage.backend", DB_TYPE);
            conf.setProperty("storage.hostname", DB_IP);
            this.graph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
            .
            .
            .
    }
```

Do you have an idea why I get this error?

Comment: Could you please attach dependencies for each project, perhaps the result of `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` ?

Comment: Thx for the dependency hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to dependencies distributed over multiple maven modules. To fix it I moved all "external" dependencies like `titan-all` to the core (or how should we call this?) maven module `2whc`. All other modules depend now only on my own modules. For example `2whc-clustering-impl` depends only on `2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl` and `2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl` does not have any dependencies at all on its own pom. However the tab effective pom of the eclipse Maven POM Editor shows for all modules the modules own dependencies and the core modules `2whc` dependecies.

pom of `2whc-clustering-impl`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>2whc</artifactId>
        <groupId>ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>2whc-clustering-impl</artifactId>

    ...

    <dependencies>      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm</groupId>
            <artifactId>2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom of `2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>2whc</artifactId>
        <groupId>ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl</artifactId>

    ...

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom of `2whc`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.uzh.ifi.ddis.dm</groupId>
    <artifactId>2whc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Two-Way Hierarchical Clustering</name>

    ...

    <modules>
        <module>2whc-clustering-api</module>
        <module>2whc-clustering-impl</module>
        <module>2whc-cluster-hierarchy-impl</module>
        <module>2whc-recommendations-impl</module>
    </modules>

    ...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.uzh.agglorecommender</groupId>
            <artifactId>inputbeans</artifactId>
            <version>0.01</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.2</version>
        </dependency>           
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <testng.version>6.8.5</testng.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```